# WCF fails to be activated after I changed client certificates configuration

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

This ASP.NET 4.0 web IIS site is used to be `Require client certificates`, but after I changed the setting to `Accept client certificates` the WCF code failed with following messages

> The service '/myapp/myservice.svc' cannot be activated due
>   to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The SSL
>   settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the
>   IIS 'Ssl, SslNegotiateCert'.. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The
>   SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of
>   the IIS 'Ssl, SslNegotiateCert'.

The ASP.NET part of the codes all work fine, not the WCF (to expose JSON) together with the site.

Any idea why?